# Improper integrals of discontinuous functions

Tags: calculus

The integrals, $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}t^n dt; \int_{-a}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^n}dt; \int_{-\infty}^{b}e^t dt; \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^n}dt$$ are what we call improper integrals. Notice that while some functions are continuous throughout, others have infinite discontinuities. Nevertheless, the above are all improper integrals. Whether they converge to a value or not is not my concern at the moment.

Let me now have a function that is bounded in an interval and has finite number of discontinuities( not infinite ), either at the ends or at places within the interval. We are to integrate this function over a finite interval. While some say that this is not an improper integral, still calling it a Riemann integral, others say it is indeed an improper integral. What am I really supposed to take this integral as?

Comment: It depends what the interval is. If $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous except at finitely many points, and $|a|, |b| < \infty$, then it is _proper_ Riemann integrable. This is a standard theorem in elementary analysis. But if at least one of $a,b$ are infinite in magnitude, then the integral is necessarily improper.